# Return public members of BL object

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, serialization

I'm trying to return a BL object from WCF server,
but I get all the private properties only.

How to return only the BL public properties?

That's the BL Class in some DLL I refernce to WCF server:

```
[Serializable()]
public class Account
{
    #region properties

    private int _accountId;
    public int AccountID
    {
        get
        {
            return _accountId;
        }
        set
        {
            _accountId = value;
        }
    }

    
    private string _title;
   public string Title
    {
        get
        {
           return _title;
        }
        set
        {
            _title= value;
        }
    }


    private string _name;
   public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _name;
        }
        set
        {
           _name= value;
        }
    }}
```

That's the WCF method in the interface:

```
   [OperationContract]
   [WebGet(UriTemplate = "{Key}/{Client}/Registrations?eventID={eventID}&regStatus={regStatus}")]
    List<Registration> GetRegistrations(string key, string client, int eventID, int regStatus);
```

The method that makes the return list:

```
public List<Registration> GetRegistrations(string key, string client, int eventID, int regStatus)
    {
        if (Validation.ValidateClient(key, client) == false)
            return null;

        List<Registration> regs = Registration.GetRegByColumnandValue(eventID, (Registration.RegStatusFlags)regStatus);
        return regs;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WCF does not use the `[Serializable]` attribute.

Write your BL object (or a DTO ) like this:

```
[DataContract]
public class Account
{  
    private int _accountId;    
    [DataMember]
    public int AccountID
    {
       // get/set
    }

    private string _title;
    [DataMember]    
    public string Title
    {
       // get/set
    }
}
```

---

The [Serializable] is wrecking the way the type is serialized, it's not suitable for WCF.

If it is embedded in another layer and you cannot remove it, then create a DTO (Data Transfer Object) class. You'll need code to copy the relevant properties, at least server-side.

Comment: the [Serializable] attribute is in my bL object.

i call and want to return it in my wcf server, but it return only those private variables

Comment: Yes, like you said in the question. You need a DataContract.

Comment: Actually, WCF can use classes that are only marked with `[Serializable]`, in which case it serializes the private fields that are not marked with `[NonSerialized]`. However, the preferred way is to do what the answerer said and use `[DataContract]`.

Comment: whats better ? create new object that inherit from the BL objects or use [DataContract]?

Comment: Don't inherit from the BL object, it will still be Serizalizable.